# Tongue positioning for Serbian ć and č

Tags: pronunciation, slavic-languages

I know that ć and č are different sounds as ć is softer than č, but do not know how the tongue should be positioned to pronounce them.

- Is ć pronounced with the tip of the tongue touching the back of the upper teeth, or touching the back of the lower teeth with the middle part touching the palate?
- Is č pronounced with the tip of the tongue on the hard palate or the soft palate, and does the tongue touch the back of the upper teeth?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.